# Not able to get the multipart image in spring from objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, spring, uiimage

I got UIImage after that i converted UIImage to JPEG and now again I'm converting into multipart file then I'm  passing to spring rest controller 
using post and storing that image into my database. but I'm getting null  MultipartFile in spring.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] 
 initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);// image is UIImage

    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@\r\n\r\n", @"imageCaption"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", @"Some Caption"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add image data
    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.jpg\r\n", @"imageFormKey"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Request reply: %@", requestReply);
    }] resume];
```

I'm passing image like above in objective c

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/livesessionimage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Response<String>> livesessionImageUpload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
 System.out.println("-------------"+file.length());// here i'm getting file null

return "";
}
```